# Angular 6 ngModel didn't change value in appcomponent

Tags: angular

I am now practicing angular & typescript and facing some simple problem.

Here is my **component.html**

```
<div>
    <input [(ngModel)]="mynumber">
    N is now {{N}}
    // some content I want to do with functions with changing mynumber
</div>
```

And my **component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
    mynumber = '1';
    N = this.mynumber;
    // some function with mynumber
}
```

The problem is, "N is now #" should change whatever I type at real time. But the changing seemed never pass to AppComponent. N just remained 1 as initial. How can I make values of `mynumber` change when I type and change affect the function too?

Comment: you don't need to assign `N = this.mynumber`.  Just use `mynumber` in your template.  `N is now {{ mynumber }}`

Comment: Actually I want to pass the ```mynumber``` value to a function in ```AppComponent``` and then display that function in HTML. So I just use these code to observe the changing of ```mynumber```. ```{{mynumber}}``` can only display the value but not pass it.

Comment: I think I fix it. Just change ```<input [(ngModel)]="mynumber">``` to  ```<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="mynumber">```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize the value of `N` to `mynumber` it happens only once and won't reflect the new changes to the value of `mynumber`.

To make it work you can do a event binding to `ngModelChange` and break up the [(x)] syntax and trigger a method in the component which will update the value of `N` on change of `mynumber`:

```
<input [ngModel]="mynumber" (ngModelChange)="valuechange($event)">
  N is now {{N}}
```

And in the component, update `N` when the method is triggered:

```
 valuechange(value){
    this.N = value;
 }
```

Although this approach is redundant and you can simply use the `mynumber` in the template expression.

Comment: @Juan please accept/upvote if this solution helped you!

Answer (score 1):

During the execution of the line

```
N = this.mynumber;
```

N is assigned the *current* value of `this.mynumber`, that is, 1. Its value isn't automatically updated when `mynumber` is changed. You can either a) ditch the redundant property `N` and just use `mynumber`, or b) update `N` it every time `mynumber` is updated.